# How to configure Coverity for IAR ARM (iccarm)

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis, coverity

I configured `Coverity` with

[image]

The build is successful, but I receive `Recoverable errors` in the system headers (see build-log.txt)

[image]

For me it’s not clear why these errors occur (build is successful) and how to configure `Coverity` that these errors don’t occur at all?

```
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227719Z|cov-build|66594|info|> cov-build 2022.3.3 (build d37b3c67c6 p-2022.3-push-69)
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227742Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2022.3.3 on Linux 5.15.0-48-generic x86_64
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227742Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Internal version numbers: d37b3c67c6 p-2022.3-push-69
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227742Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227757Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Dumping from hostname : ci
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227757Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Platform info:
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Sysname = Linux
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Release = 5.15.0-48-generic
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Machine = x86_64
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227764Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227780Z|cov-build|66594|info|> cov-build command: cov-build --dir build/test/icc cmake --build . 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227786Z|cov-build|66594|info|> cov-build expanded command: cov-build --dir build/test/icc cmake --build . 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227957Z|cov-build|66594|info|> build command: /usr/bin/cmake --build .
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227966Z|cov-build|66594|info|> thunk command: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin/cov-internal-thunk.sh cmake --build .
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227966Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227974Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set UseSharedCompilation to false.
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227982Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_BIN to /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227993Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_SITE_CC to iccarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.227999Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_SITE_CC_CAPTURE_DESCENDANTS to 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228005Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_TEMP to /tmp/cov-repo/61cbee90e75bbbfcd24d03a3fa896a77
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228015Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_COMMON_TEMP to /tmp
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228023Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_IDIR to /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228048Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_OUTPUT to /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/build-log.txt
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228053Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_LOG to /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/build-log.txt
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228061Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_OUTPUT_ENCODING to US-ASCII
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228066Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_SYSTEM_ENCODING to US-ASCII
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228073Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_EMIT to /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/emit
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228095Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_IS_COMPILER to 0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228100Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_TOP_PROCESS to 0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228103Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_IS_COMPILER_DESCENDANT to 0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228107Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Set COVERITY_DISENGAGE_EXES to "qemuwrapper;qemu-aarch64;qemu-alpha;qemu-arm;qemu-armeb;qemu-cris;qemu-i386;qemu-m68k;qemu-microblaze;qemu-mips;qemu-mipsel;qemu-nios2;qemu-ppc;qemu-ppc64;qemu-ppc64abi32;qemu-sh4;qemu-sh4eb;qemu-sparc;qemu-sparc32plus;qemu-sparc64;qemu-x86_64"
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228123Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228123Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228123Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Dumping Environment Variables:
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228123Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228142Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JENKINS_HOME=/home/repo/.jenkins
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228146Z|cov-build|66594|info|> GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=5ecdaedd1ad5f4173cc5aa22a7ff06a2d7aa659b
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228151Z|cov-build|66594|info|> CI=true
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228154Z|cov-build|66594|info|> RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL=http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/xxx/324/display/redirect?page=changes
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228158Z|cov-build|66594|info|> HOSTNAME=ci
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228167Z|cov-build|66594|info|> NODE_LABELS=built-in
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228171Z|cov-build|66594|info|> GIT_COMMIT=c8902b01612b12a90701b3949e8be64e65775ba7
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228175Z|cov-build|66594|info|> HOME=/home/repo
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228179Z|cov-build|66594|info|> HUDSON_COOKIE=94d36788-17b8-4a07-a30e-6e22a28d86dc
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228183Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=durable-d67ab9cc6fd15cde89a20cb1f752777478da5dc72dc942e65e59bab789c478c1
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228187Z|cov-build|66594|info|> WORKSPACE=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228190Z|cov-build|66594|info|> CROSS_ROOT=/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228194Z|cov-build|66594|info|> NODE_NAME=built-in
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228198Z|cov-build|66594|info|> RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL=http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/xxx/324/display/redirect?page=artifacts
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228201Z|cov-build|66594|info|> ASM=iasmarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228205Z|cov-build|66594|info|> STAGE_NAME=Icc Arm + Coverity
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228209Z|cov-build|66594|info|> EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228213Z|cov-build|66594|info|> GIT_BRANCH=origin/master
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228217Z|cov-build|66594|info|> TERM=xterm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228220Z|cov-build|66594|info|> RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL=http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/xxx/324/display/redirect?page=tests
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228224Z|cov-build|66594|info|> BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#324
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228228Z|cov-build|66594|info|> HUDSON_HOME=/home/repo/.jenkins
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228232Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JOB_BASE_NAME=xxx
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228236Z|cov-build|66594|info|> PATH=/opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin:/opt/SEGGER/JLink_V766:/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/common/bin:/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/bin:/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228240Z|cov-build|66594|info|> TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../../cmake/platforms/$TOOLCHAIN_FILENAME
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228244Z|cov-build|66594|info|> BUILD_ID=324
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228247Z|cov-build|66594|info|> BUILD_TAG=jenkins-xxx-324
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228251Z|cov-build|66594|info|> GIT_URL=file:///home/repo/repository
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228255Z|cov-build|66594|info|> BUILD_NUMBER=324
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228259Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=a1e213c4-5eae-41f4-bff8-c26bcc76eacd
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228262Z|cov-build|66594|info|> CXX=iccarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228266Z|cov-build|66594|info|> RUN_DISPLAY_URL=http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/xxx/324/display/redirect
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228270Z|cov-build|66594|info|> HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=e67de7100ca0e18a
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228274Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JOB_DISPLAY_URL=http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/xxx/display/redirect
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228278Z|cov-build|66594|info|> JOB_NAME=xxx
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228282Z|cov-build|66594|info|> PWD=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228286Z|cov-build|66594|info|> GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=6ec26434a11544368ba767770e88c74dd3391906
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228290Z|cov-build|66594|info|> WORKSPACE_TMP=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx@tmp
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228293Z|cov-build|66594|info|> CC=iccarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228297Z|cov-build|66594|info|> TOOLCHAIN_FILENAME=toolchain-iar-iccarm.cmake
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228301Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_PREV_XML_CATALOG_FILES=
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228305Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_TOP_CONFIG=/tmp/cov-repo/61cbee90e75bbbfcd24d03a3fa896a77/cov-configure/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228309Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_BUILD_INVOCATION_ID=1
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228313Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_CONFIG_FILE=/opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228317Z|cov-build|66594|info|> UseSharedCompilation=false
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228321Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_BIN=/opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228325Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_SITE_CC=iccarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228332Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_SITE_CC_CAPTURE_DESCENDANTS=
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228336Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_TEMP=/tmp/cov-repo/61cbee90e75bbbfcd24d03a3fa896a77
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228340Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_COMMON_TEMP=/tmp
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228344Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_IDIR=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228348Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_REWRITE_FROM=
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228352Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_REWRITE_TO=
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228356Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_ENABLE_JAVA_ANNOTATION_FRAMEWORK_SUPPORT=1
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228360Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_OUTPUT=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/build-log.txt
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228364Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_LOG=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/build-log.txt
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228367Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_OUTPUT_ENCODING=US-ASCII
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228371Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_SYSTEM_ENCODING=US-ASCII
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228375Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_EMIT=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/emit
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228379Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_IS_COMPILER=0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228383Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_TOP_PROCESS=0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228387Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_IS_COMPILER_DESCENDANT=0
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228390Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_DISENGAGE_EXES=qemuwrapper;qemu-aarch64;qemu-alpha;qemu-arm;qemu-armeb;qemu-cris;qemu-i386;qemu-m68k;qemu-microblaze;qemu-mips;qemu-mipsel;qemu-nios2;qemu-ppc;qemu-ppc64;qemu-ppc64abi32;qemu-sh4;qemu-sh4eb;qemu-sparc;qemu-sparc32plus;qemu-sparc64;qemu-x86_64
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228395Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_COMPILER_PATH_MISMATCH_FILE=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/has_path_mismatches
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228399Z|cov-build|66594|info|> COVERITY_PATHLESS_CONFIGS_FILE=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/has_pathless_configs
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228405Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228405Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228405Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Dumping configuration:
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228405Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228415Z|cov-build|66594|info|> User/default configuration:
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228415Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Configuration read from: command-line
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Node: coverity
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: config
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|>     Node: include Value: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: config
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|>     Node: prevent
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|>       Node: dir Value: /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228421Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Configuration read from: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Node: coverity
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: cit_version Value: 1
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: config
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|>     Node: include Value: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/template-iar_cxx_arm-config-0/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228444Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Configuration read from: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/template-iar_cxx_arm-config-0/coverity_config.xml
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Node: coverity
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: cit_version Value: 1
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: config
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>     Node: build
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>       Node: compiler
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: template_compiler Value: true
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: comp_name Value: iccarm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: comp_translator Value: iar_cxx:arm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: comp_lang Value: C++
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: comp_generic Value: iar/arm
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>       Node: options
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: id Value: iar_cxx:arm-iccarm-.*
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: opt_preinclude_file Value: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/template-iar_cxx_arm-config-0/../user_nodefs.h
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>         Node: begin_command_line_config
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|>   Node: md5 Value: 5f6642eb878a88db1dfb16309fb4338b
2022-10-20T13:38:11.228461Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:11.230365Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Using LD_PRELOAD = 
/opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin/libcapture-linux64-${PLATFORM}.so
[73713] EXECUTING: /opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/bin/ielfdumparm --source test.out
...
[73394] EXECUTING: grep dev
[STATUS] Compiling /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/src/nodynalloc/new_del.cpp
/opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin/cov-emit --dir=/home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-repo/61cbee90e75bbbfcd24d03a3fa896a77/cov-configure --ignore_path=/tmp/cov-repo/61cbee90e75bbbfcd24d03a3fa896a77/cov-repo/ab3163e8db5f4764170d37b222c3d703 --pre_preinclude /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/emit/ci/config/5092253b194ec0553c3a9de3b66cf08a/iar_cxx_arm-config-0/coverity-macro-compat.h --pre_preinclude /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/emit/ci/config/5092253b194ec0553c3a9de3b66cf08a/iar_cxx_arm-config-0/coverity-compiler-compat.h --c++ --dollar --allow_qualified_anonymous_unions --allow_global_anonymous_union --no_const_string_literals --unsigned_chars --trigraphs --enable_user_sections --add_type_modifier=__absolute,__big_endian --add_type_modifier=__little_endian --add_type_modifier=__packed,__pcrel --add_type_modifier=__sbrel,__global_reg --add_type_modifier=__coverity_16bit_float --allow_qualified_operator_new_return --lazy_hex_pp_number --short_enums --user_defined_literals --macro_preempts_udl_suffix --ppp_translator "replace/_Mem \*operator new(\[\])? _Mem/*operator new$1" --ppp_translator "replace/operator new mem/operator new" --ppp_translator replace/0.Infinity/1.0\/0.0 --ppp_translator replace/0.Na[Nn]/0.0\/0.0 --allow_injected_template_symbol --arg_dependent_overload --class_scope_noexcept --no_predefined_cplusplus -w --no_predefines --comp_ver 9030001 --char_bit_size=8 --wchar_t_keyword --no_multiline_string --ignore_calling_convention --no_enable_80bit_float --no_enable_128bit_float --macro_stack_pragmas --type_traits_helpers --rtti --inline_keyword --has_include_macro --has_include_next_macro --has_cpp_attribute_macro --no_predefines --preinclude /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/config/template-iar_cxx_arm-config-0/../user_nodefs.h --c++17 --c++17 --no_rtti --no_exceptions --short_enums --gnu_version=50400 --macro_stack_pragmas --add_type_modifier=__data:1,__code --no_stdarg_builtin --sys_include /opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c --sys_include /opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/aarch32 --sys_include /opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/cpp --ppp_translator replace/(#include\s+)u8/$1 --ppp_translator replace/(#define\s+_DLIB_CONFIG_FILE_HEADER_NAME\s+)u8/$1 --ppp_translator replace/(#define\s+_DLIB_CONFIG_FILE_STRING\s+)u8/$1 --ppp_translator replace/(typedef\s+_Align_type<)::/$1 -DNDEBUG -U__EXCEPTIONS -D__coverity_undefine___EXCEPTIONS -D__FAR_RUNTIME_ATTRIBUTE__=__near_func -U__FOR_DEBUG__ -D__coverity_undefine___FOR_DEBUG__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -U__PLACEMENT_DELETE -D__coverity_undefine___PLACEMENT_DELETE -U__RTTI -D__coverity_undefine___RTTI -U__STDC_VERSION__ -D__coverity_undefine___STDC_VERSION__ -U__coverity_undefine___STDC_VERSION__ -D__coverity_undefine___coverity_undefine___STDC_VERSION__ -U__cpp_exceptions -D__coverity_undefine___cpp_exceptions -U__cpp_rtti -D__coverity_undefine___cpp_rtti --type_sizes=dex8Pfilw4s2 --type_alignments=dex8Pfilw4s2 --size_t_type=j --ptrdiff_t_type=i /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/src/nodynalloc/new_del.cpp 
[73393] EXECUTING: /bin/mount
"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xstddef0", line 16: warning #59:
          function call is not allowed in a constant expression
    #if _HAS_NOEXCEPT || !_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
        ^

[73399] EXECUTING: grep dev
"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xstddef0", line 16: warning #59:
          function call is not allowed in a constant expression
    #if _HAS_NOEXCEPT || !_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
        ^

[73398] EXECUTING: /bin/mount
"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xstddef0", line 16: warning #59:
          function call is not allowed in a constant expression
    #if _HAS_NOEXCEPT || !_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
        ^

"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/yvals.h", line 159: warning #59:
          function call is not allowed in a constant expression
    #if _HAS_NOEXCEPT
        ^

"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xstddef0", line 16: warning #59:
          function call is not allowed in a constant expression
    #if _HAS_NOEXCEPT || !_HAS_EXCEPTIONS
        ^

"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xmemnew", line 7: warning #59: function
          call is not allowed in a constant expression
  #if __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)
      ^

"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xmemnew", line 7: warning #59: function
          call is not allowed in a constant expression
  #if __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)
      ^

[73403] EXECUTING: /bin/mount
[73404] EXECUTING: grep dev
"/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c/xmemnew", line 7: warning #59: function
          call is not allowed in a constant expression
  #if __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)
...
2022-10-20T13:38:39.392031Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Invoking cov-security-da with commands: /opt/coverity/cov-analysis-2022-3/bin/cov-security-da --dir /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc
2022-10-20T13:38:39.401624Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Dynamic analyzer took 9 ms
2022-10-20T13:38:39.401624Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Build time (cov-build overall): 00:00:28.195804
2022-10-20T13:38:39.401624Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402216Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Build time (C/C++ emits total): 00:06:17.288925
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402216Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402216Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|> Emitted 15 C/C++ compilation units (100%) successfully
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|> [WARNING] Recoverable errors were encountered during 12 of these C/C++ compilation units.
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|> 15 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|>  For more details, please look at: 
2022-10-20T13:38:39.402240Z|cov-build|66594|info|>     /home/repo/.jenkins/workspace/xxx/build/test/icc/build/test/icc/build-log.txt
```

Comment: Who's files are those? Applications shouldn't create identifiers using underscore + upper case or double underscore, since those are reserved for the compiler. That is, IAR is allowed to name things like that but Coverity is not, nor is your application.

Comment: The files under `/opt/iarsystems/bxarm-9.30.1/arm/inc/c` are from IAR. I didn't modify them. They are used via e.g., `#include <new>` in my sources and for some reasons `Coverity` doesn't realize that these files are system includes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question in the title (how to configure for IAR), your `cov-configure` command line looks right to me.

The warning messages (`function call is not allowed in a constant expression`) are from the Coverity compiler, which believes the input is not valid C++, and hence is warning about it.  But these warnings appear to be of a kind that will not cause any problem for analysis; the compiler just notes the problem but continues anyway, like with any other compiler warning.  (When the analysis runs, if there is a consequence for fidelity, you would see [`RW.ROUTINE_NOT_EMITTED`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984592/what-is-the-meaning-of-coverity-warning-rw-routine-not-emitted) issues reported.)

Because the problem arises from inside the Coverity compiler, there isn't any easy way for the user to suppress these messages.  My recommendation would be to create a minimal reproducer and send it to Coverity support for them to eventually fix in the product.  If you really want to fix it yourself, you could probably fix it using a `ppp_translator` ("ppp" stands for "pre-preprocessor") element in the compiler configuration to rewrite the offending code on the fly, but that's a non-trivial undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see (contains a workaround and also the information with which release it shall be fixed)

https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/warning-59-function-call-is-not-allowed-in-a-constant-expression-if-HAS-NOEXCEPT